# How to visual clear Reflection in freeform shape

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to visual the freeform shape that uses the mirror polished stainless steel. Something like Cloud gate

[image]

In render the reflection is too distorted because the curve shape is quite complex. I want to avoid it without changing 3D.

I tried to add normal vector to change the reflection but it didn't work.
Does anybody have idea to solve this to make a nice render?

[image][image]

Comment: Are you sure you're not just lacking geometry? 
I trust that is a spherical HDRi to light your scene?
Can we see a wireframe or flat shaded version?
You get the hint?
Also: Normal input is for normal map, not geometry vectors.

Comment: Thank for your comment. Yes. I have a context. But I got the same result. The reflection is not clear. I attached the file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PN1zVnpHi2cMJOveBXTE-eGCXy9RML-9/view?usp=sharing.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit harsh yesterday. 
In your .blend you have an empty normal map, you might want to remove that as it has no effect. 
Also you had a landscape without textures, is that supposed to be reflected as gray?
And finally: What's wrong now? The reflections look a bit off, but I tried every trick in the book to fix the normals and I think this is simply the way a curved surface like that is supposed to behave.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Yes. I think I have to play with the shape to get better result. Thank for your time.